# Why onComplete not fired when an infinite stream is switchMap'ed

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, switchmap

Using `RxJava 2.2.8`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Some data")
            .subscribe(
                    s -> System.out.println(s),
                    e -> System.err.println(e),
                    () -> System.out.println("Completed")
            );
```

**Output**

```
Some data
Completed
```

My question is why `onComplete` never gets called for the following?

```
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .switchMap(t -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Some data"))
            .subscribe(
                    s -> System.out.println(s),
                    e -> System.err.println(e),
                    () -> System.out.println("Completed")
            );
```

**Output**

```
Some data
Some data
Some data
...
```

I understand `Observable.interval` will create a never ending stream, so no `onComplete`. My understanding of `switchMap` is that it returns an observable which fires events produced by the inner observable (cancelling any pending and flattening), in this case  `Observable.fromCallable`.

Now, this 'inner' observable does have a definite end (unlike the outer observable), so why doesn't `onComplete` gets called on this inner Observable?

Why isn't the output like this?

```
Some data
Completed
Some data
Completed
Some data
Completed
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#switchMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

> The resulting ObservableSource completes if both the upstream
>   ObservableSource and the last inner ObservableSource

Since *upstream ObservableSource* is an infinite stream, the resulting *Observable* will not complete.

Also note that according to the [observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html), onComplete indicates the observable has terminated and it will not emit any further items in the future, so you will never see "Completed" followed by some other items regardless of your implementation.